# "this" variable get lost when passing a function from Parent to Child Component - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a component to show Data.

In my `Parent Component` I am creating a config obj which will be passed to the `ItemViewer Component`

```
export class ProcessListComponent implements OnInit {

process_list: any;
configObj: {};

constructor(public http: HttpClient){}

ngOnInit() {
    // this is the config Obj
    this.configObj = {
        data : this.getAll,
        fields : {
            title : 'Id',
            body :[
                { name : 'Name' , field : 'name'},
                { name: 'Final Material', field : 'final_material'},
                { name : 'Rivision' , field : 'revision'}
            ]
        },
        selectionChanged : this.selectionChangeDetection
    }
}

selectionChangeDetection(item){
    alert(item)
    // some events here, some actions here related to visiblity
}

// function to fetch Obj List
getAll(option: string) {
    // console.log(this)
    return (function(extra_option: string){
        const url: string = 'http://localhost:3000/process_list' + extra_option;
        return this.http.get(url);  // <-- Error comes at this line. How to handle it ??
    })(option);
}
}
```

I pass this obj to `ItemViewer Component` and handles it as below:

```
export class ItemViewerComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() config;
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.config.selectionChanged('it works'); // <-- This function works
    this.config.data()
        .subscribe(data => console.log(data)); // <-- Error here
}

}
```

Now, when I run this I get

> ProcessListComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'http' of undefined
>       at process.list.component.ts:40
>       at Object.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/features/process/list/process.list.component.ts.ProcessListComponent.getAll [as data] (process.list.component.ts:41)
>       at ItemViewerComponent .webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/common/ICV/icv.component.ts.ItemViewerComponent .ngOnInit (item-viewer.component.ts:14)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10843)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12341)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12284)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13141)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:13082)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ProcessListComponent.html:1)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13067)

Now, I know that I am getting this error because `this` does not have `http` var of `ProcessListComponent`.

The same config used to work with `$http` when I had the application in **Angular1.X** and I used to pass

```
 function getAll(option) {
            return (function (ur_option){
                return $http.get('http://XYZ&units=metric&'+ur_option)
            })(option)
        }
```

### Update

Thanks to [ConnorsFan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009922/connorsfan)& Radonirina Maminiaina: below code worked

```
getAll = (option: string) => {
   return ((extra_option: string) => {
       const url: string = 'http://localhost:3000/process_list' + extra_option;
       return this.http.get(url);
    })(option);
 }
```

Comment: In addition to defining the function returned by `getAll` as an arrow function, you should also declare `getAll` itself as an arrow function: `public getAll = (option: string) => { ... }` (because `getAll` is used as a callback). Or set it in the configuration like this: `data : (option: string) => { ... }`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan : Thank you so much. `getAll = (option: string) =>` did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use arrow function if you want to keep `this` context.

> Arrows are a function shorthand using the => syntax. They are
>   syntactically similar to the related feature in C#, Java 8 and
>   CoffeeScript. They support both expression and statement bodies.
>   **Unlike functions, arrows share the same lexical `this` as their
>   surrounding code**. If an arrow is inside another function, it shares
>   the “arguments” variable of its parent function.

```
getAll(option: string) {
    // console.log(this)
   return ((extra_option: string) => {
       const url: string = 'http://localhost:3000/process_list' + extra_option;
       return this.http.get(url);  // <-- Error comes at this line. How to handle it ??
    })(option);
 }
```

Or you have to save this into a variable:

```
getAll(option: string) {
    // console.log(this)
    let $this = this;
    return (function(extra_option: string){
        const url: string = 'http://localhost:3000/process_list' + extra_option;
        return $this.http.get(url);  // <-- Error comes at this line. How to handle it ??
    })(option);
}
```

You can find more explaination [here](https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#arrows-and-lexical-this).

**UPDATE**:
When you call your `getAll` method, you will do this:

```
this.getAll('options')()
```

Or am I wrong?

So why just do it:

```
getAll(option: string) {
    const url: string = 'http://localhost:3000/process_list' + option;
    return this.http.get(url);
}
```

Or I don't understand what are you want to do?

Comment: `this` is getting changed. Fat arrow didnt work. checking the attached link

Comment: update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It was really helpful , although **Connor** suggestion fixed the small bug which was there in your answer. Upvoting ur answer for the link.